# Passing Values to Controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

I'm trying to allow users to 'favorite' links (that is, create a new `Favorite` record with their `user_id` and the `link_id`) This is what I have so far..

When I click favorite (as a user), the new record is assigned to the user_id but the link_id field is nil. How can I pass the `link_id` into my `FavoritesController`?

[My View Code](https://gist.github.com/1391742)

**Added** [Link Model Code](https://gist.github.com/1391822)

```
class FavoritesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
    @favorite = @user.favorites.create :link_id => params[:id]
    redirect_to :back
  end
end
```

The `Favorite` model belongs to `:user` and `:link`

Note: I've also tried [this](https://gist.github.com/1391738) but when I click 'favorite', there's an error "Couldn't find Link without an ID."

**Update**

```
<%= link_to "Favorite", :controller => :favorites, :action => :create, :link_id => link.id %>
```

with

```
class FavoritesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
    @favorite = @user.favorites.create :link_id => :params[:link_id]
    redirect_to :back
  end
end
```

Returns "can't convert Symbol into Integer"

```
app/controllers/favorites_controller.rb:4:in []
app/controllers/favorites_controller.rb:4:in create
```

I've tried forcing it into an Integer several ways with `.to_i`

Comment: can you post the code for the link?

Comment: you use `link_to "Favorite", :controller => :favorites, :action => :create` and don't pass any `link_id` to action. Therefore you get your error message

Comment: How should this link_id pass be done? I've tried `link_to "Favorite", :controller => :favorites, :action => :create, :link_id => link.id` which returns the error "Couldn't find Link without an ID."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following

**In your view:**

```
<%= link_to "Favorite", :controller => :favorites, :action => :create, :link_id => link.id %>
```

**In your controller:**

```
class FavoritesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @user = User.find(:first, :conditions => ["id = ?", session[:id]])
    @favorite = @user.favorites.create
    @favorite.update_attributes(:link_id => params[:link_id])
    redirect_to :back
  end
end
```

Just as a side note, when finding records, i tend to use:

```
.find(:first, :conditions => ["id = ?", session[:id]])
```

as it will escape most stuff submitted by user and returns one record.

I have broken the steps up in your controller, but you could combine them into one like this:

```
def create
    @user = User.find(:first, :conditions => ["id = ?", session[:id]])
    @favorite = @user.favorites.create(:link_id => params[:link_id])
    redirect_to :back
end
```

hopefully that should work

Comment: + 1 Thanks @Hishalv! It works when setting the `:link_id` separately with `update_attribtues`

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
@user = User.find(session[:user_id])

@favorite = Favorite.create :link_id => params[:id]

@favorite.user = @user
```

Comment: I'm confused by the third line of your code. What's it purpose?

Comment: I was thinking that your problem was in creating the object. This is why splitted your second line. But your problem is really at params.

Answer (score 0):

It fails because params[:id] is nil. Put

```
throw params
```

at the beginning of the create method and check what you have available there. Please psot also the code in your view.